Is it possible to output different soundtracks from movies to different output devices?
For example, if I have a movie in MKV or another format, or a DVD with multiple soundtracks in different languages, can we watch it simultaneously in two languages? I want to watch the movie in English, and my wife wants to watch it in Ukrainian. Is it possible, for instance, that we both wear headphones, with each set of headphones playing a different soundtrack?
For example, can VLC broadcast two soundtracks to two different IP addresses, and let's say, use our phones to listen to them? Or is there any other solution?

In theory yes a single program could output to many sources but I don't know any that actually do it. I know that If you have media on a Plex Server then the Plex Client programs you install on various devices can be set to "Watch together" and have their own audio settings per client.

Few years ago I answered this question about mplayers playing in sync. I guess two instances playing the same video with different audio can be synced without tricks.
